# Fallback_cb is messing around with containers

Tags: navigation

I have the following code in place for a custom menu area:

```
$wp_nav_header = array( 
    'container' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
    'theme_location' => 'primaryheader',
    'depth' => 0,);
wp_nav_menu( $wp_nav_header);
```

It works fine when there **is** a menu in place, and outputs:

```
<div id="nav-main">
<div class="sf-menu">
<ul><li...
```

However, when it's **falling back**, it outputs:

```
<div id="nav-main">
<ul id="menu-default" class="sf-menu"><li...
```

Needless to say, this is throwing off my design as it's adding these classes (for which I have no styling) & stripping suckerfish , but makes my nav disappear (despite showing up in source).

Anybody encounter this before?

Thank you!

Comment: Adding what classes? the only difference i can see between the two pieces of code you've posted is the ID attribute on the unordered list.

Comment: That's correct, it adds id=menu-default, adding sf-menu to the second also didn't resolve the issue (as I thought it was suckerfish). Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you are missing the container div so if you change your fallback to a custom function you can pass parameters to wp_page_menu that give you a bit of control over it and add your missing div try:

```
$wp_nav_header = array( 
    'container' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',
    'fallback_cb' => 'my_fallback_menu',
    'theme_location' => 'primaryheader',
    'depth' => 0,);
wp_nav_menu( $wp_nav_header);


function my_fallback_menu(){
    echo '<div class="sf-menu">';
    $args = array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'menu_class'  => '',
        'include'     => '',
        'exclude'     => '',
        'echo'        => true,
        'show_home'   => false,
        'link_before' => '',
        'link_after'  => '' );
    wp_page_menu($args);
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Hope this helps